# Unable to set column elements as hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to set the first column elements as hyperlinks redirecting to another page..but somehow it doesn't seem to work no matter what I try.

```
reportTable.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text = report.reportId.ToString();
                TableCell tCell = new TableCell();

                tCell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(" report.reportId.ToString      ()"));
                // Create Hyperlink Web Server control and add to cell
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink h = new HyperLink();
                h.Text = reportTable.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text = report.reportId.ToString();
                h.NavigateUrl = "~/manage.aspx";
                tCell.Controls.Add(h);

                reportTable.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text = bench.mechId;
                reportTable.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text = bench.elecId;
                reportTable.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text = bench.name;
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?  Have you any more code to show what you are doing with this table, and where?

Comment: This is kinda weird `new LiteralControl(" report.reportId.ToString      ()")`, can you expand on what doesn't work ?

Comment: the column elements are not getting set to hyperlinks though i have added them in the item template as well.This is fetching the reportid's from the datasource.The namespaces have been compiled and added to the reference assembly as well.

Comment: each row has a checkbox for the reports and a separate handler function written for 'select_click', i would like to set the first coloumn as hyperlinks instead of the checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asp.net Grid and data controls are very good for data binding.

Also they provide Item templates that can be customized to include links, drop down lists, etc.

Do not populate your grid by manually creating all the controls. That totally defeats the purpose of using a grid.

e.g:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="ReportsGridView" 
  DataSourceID="ReportsDataSource"
  AllowPaging="true" 
  AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
  runat="server">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server"
          ID="RedirectButton"
          CommandName="Manage"
          PostBackUrl="~/manage.aspx"
          Text="Manage" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" 
      HeaderText="Report Name"/> 
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: this is what i first tried but then i read somewhere that hyperlink was a better option but alas both of them aren't working

Comment: A link button will get rendered to a hyperlink in html rendered to the browser.